# Can I safely delete files from /Library/Keychains

Tags: catalina, keychain, disk-space

I'm having serious problems with disk space, after some investigation I discovered that ~400GB (not a mistake!) of my 1TB HDD is filled with files in `/Library/Keychains`.

It's about 30k files of approx. size +100mb each with name pattern `System.keychain.sb-*` -i.e. `System.keychain.sb-2531a98b-XTNIjR`.

As in the title my question is if I can remove them, and how to do it in most safely way? Should I delete them from the Keychain app (these are probably Private keys) or just delete files from folder directly?

Additional subquestion is what caused that big amount of these, and how can I prevent from it in the future?

OS: Catalina 10.15.7
iMac 27 late 2012

Comment: I don't know if it's safe to delete them, but I'd run the Keychain Access utility, select the System keychain, and see what it shows.

Comment: FYI: Keychain utility was little unclear to me (also a lot of items), just started to remove some files from mentioned folder and checking system stability, everything was fine. Finally, I removed all these and released 400 GB of HDD without any issues. What's interesting, they don't regenerate, so there was probably some misconfiguration in the past.